# How to refresh contextmenustrip items or refreshing form's items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application

Basically, i am creating a raw-based web browser application. Bookmarks are added in contextmenu toolstripitem either from using "star" button or via another form. When added using another form, it is not refreshing the contextmenu items which are added from another form in the main form.

MainForm View:

[mainform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW7Ga.png)

Favourites/Bookmarks View:
[bookmarks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjSYH.png)
[updatebookmarks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4riC.png)

This is how it is added via another form:
[addbookmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkILm.png)
[addbookmark2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDUvu.png)

Code Preview:

Star Button:

```cs
private void favButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(inputUrlBox.Text != "")
            {
                var item = inputUrlBox.Text.ToString();
                
                if(!favouritesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Cast<ToolStripMenuItem>().Any(x => x.Text == item))
                {
                    try {
                        Properties.Settings.Default.BookmarksList.Add(item + ",null");
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                        foreach (var bookmark in Properties.Settings.Default.BookmarksList) {
                            var link = bookmark.Split(',')[0].ToString();
                            favouritesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(link);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { 
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Bookmark already exists!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Moving directly to "Add" in another form's button (this is written in BookmarkWindow Form):

```cs
        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddBookmarkWindow form = new AddBookmarkWindow();
            form.ShowDialog(this);

        }
```

In AddBookMark's Form (AddBookmkarkWindow.cs):

```cs
if ((isUri) && (linkinput != null && linkinput.Length > 0) && (nameinput != null && nameinput.Length > 0))
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.BookmarksList.Add(linkinput + "," + nameinput);
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();


                MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
                mw.updatebookmarkstab(linkinput);
                this.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Added!");
            }
```

This "updatebookmarkstab" function is in mainwindow/mainform:

```cs
 public void updatebookmarkstab(string item)
        {
            menuStrip1.Refresh();
            contextMenuStrip1.Refresh();
            favouritesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item);
            
        }
```

What I expect is, once i add bookmark(s) from another form, I want it to be showed in main form's contextmenustrip item just like how "star" works.

Anyone has any idea on how to refresh menuitems from another form or has a better solution to provide this view.

Comment: `MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();` this creates a new instance of your main windows and adds the bookmarks there. You should use the existing MainWindow instance.

Comment: Used this and it worked, ty.
`var instance = Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainWindow>().Single();
                instance.updatebookmarkstab(linkinput);`